# veranda attached to house

Tags: shelter

I want to build a veranda to my house 21 ft wide. A beam will be supported 6 ft from the house by 2 6x6 posts on footings and 2 ft from each end "ctr span 16ft". A sloped roof will extend from the  house and extend 2 ft past. What size beam do I need, no load other than snow.

Comment: Where do you live so we know about wind loads and seismic loads?

Comment: wind load is not an issue. as i am in a sheltered area away from the prevailing winds south westerlys. I am in Canada just north of the US border 0n the west coast. seismic do not have a whole lot of information